# Get selected dropdown object on edit button click - angular 4

Tags: angular

i have a drop down that contains the list of categories

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 nopadding">
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pc.profile_characteristic_category_id" name="profile_characteristic_category_id"> 
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.profile_characteristic_category_id">{{ category.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Next to the drop down is the actions button.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 nopadding">
    <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench action-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#addCategoryModalBox" (click)="displayNewCategoryForm()">Add</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#addCategoryModalBox" (click)="editProfileCharacteristicCategory()">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

Suppose that the drop down is having value as Category 3 and the edit button is clicked,
I need to get the selected category object when the edit button is clicked.

{id: 3, 'name: Category 3', pid: 272, profile_characteristic_category_id: 1001}

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sure, start by implementing a getter

```
get selectedOption() {
  return this.categories
    .find(c => c.profile_characteristic_category_id === this.pc.profile_characteristic_category_id) || null;
}
```

This will return the selected option, and null if the options isn't found.

Now, you can just use it with your edit button

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#addCategoryModalBox" (click)="editProfileCharacteristicCategory(selectedOption)">Edit</a></li>
```

Comment: Or he could use `[(ngModel)]="pc.selectedCategory"` and  `[ngValue]="category"`, and `pc.selectedCatehory` would directly refer to the selected category object.

Comment: Well if he could do that, you could create an answer to explain it :)

Comment: Sure, but your answer is already a good one, and I upvoted it. Just wanted to suggest another option. Don't hesitate to amend your answer.

Comment: I won't, because I have never used that, hence I don't know if it works, and I won't add something I'm not sure is working. But feel free to do it yourself if you know it works !

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @trichetriche's answer is to directly use the category object itsef as the model of the select box, instead of its `profile_characteristic_category_id`:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pc.selectedCategory" name="category"> 
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category">{{ category.name }}</option>
</select>
```

The selected category object itself would now be stored in `pc.selectedCategory`, and you would simply have to use

```
(click)="editProfileCharacteristicCategory(pc.selectedCategory)"
```